# Total gas flow stoppage in Weber Propane grill

Tags: propane

We have a Weber Genesis II propane gas grill where suddenly, there is no gas flow at all. My wife was grilling when the tank (standard 20lb) ran out. She connected another talk and continued cooking. The next time she went to use the grill, there was no gas flow to any any part of the grill.

We tried switching to a fresh tank but this did not change anything.

The regulator hose goes to a block where there is a tap off to a side burner and the main tube continues to the main grill. The side burner also gets no gas flow so I'm assuming the problem is in the regulator.

I read that these regulators have a safety system where they will close up if a possible leak is detected. I have found three slightly different procedures for resetting the regulator:

1. Turn off burners, turn off tank, remove tank, turn on burners, wait, turn off burners, reconnect tank, from [tasteofhome.com](https://www.tasteofhome.com/article/how-to-reset-the-propane-regulator-on-a-gas-grill/).
2. Turn off tank, turn off burners, wait, from the Weber manual.
3. Turn off burners, turn on tank, wait, from a friend with a similar grill.

I have tried all of these with no resolution of the problem.

Am I missing anything? Is there another procedure to reset the regulator?

Comment: Check the connection that you tighten onto the tank - maybe there is a blockage there. A tank supplier told me those tanks get bits of dirt in them…