# Cannot remove regulator from Weber propane grill

Tags: propane

I just posted a question about resetting the regulator on my Weber Genesis II propane grill [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/281296/total-gas-flow-stoppage-in-weber-propane-grill). There is no gas flow and I am unable to reset the regulator.

My next idea was to just replace the regulator and I went to a big-box hardware store and purchased a replacement regulator with hose. However, I am unable to remove the old hose.

Here is a photo of the hose screwed onto the block:
[image]

The lower hose is going to the old regulator, the top tube goes to the main burner valves and the side tube goes to the side burner valve.

I am unable to unscrew the hose from the block, there is just no give. In fact, the block use to be straight up and down; I have bent the mounting bracket. I have tried with a vice lock on the body of the block (over the side tube) and even pulling/pushing between the two wrenches gives nothing.

I have also tried spraying WD40 on the junction and waiting several hours and that changed nothing.

I have examined the threads on the new regulator tube and they are standard threads ("righty tighty, lefty") so I think I am turning in the right direction.

BTW, the regulator tube came attached from the Weber factory.

Anyone have any suggestions on anything to try? Am I missing something?

Comment: since you can see the treads and your description is confusing to me, find the beginning of it and see which way it goes, to the left or right

Comment: Have you tried asking Weber? The threads on the new regulator, unless it is explicitly marked as being for this model, are not necessarily the same as the threads on the old one (probably are, but...). And Weber may have used a thread-locking compound to try to ensure this connection never comes loose accidentally. If it were me, I'd be tempted to see if the other connections can be loosened any more easily and the part dismounted from the bracket so I could work on it "in hand" or in a vise rather than having the grill body getting in the way.

Comment: @keshlam We didn't ask Weber because it happened on Saturday. We have since called them am I'm posting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is now Monday, we called Weber. The grill is under a 10-year warranty and they are send us the correct replacement part.

Apparently, it is not a standard part, as @keshlam  suggested. What they are sending us is the regulator, hose **plus the block** as an assembly.